# Docker container can't connect to the bus : couldn't parse server address

Tags: docker, electron, dockerfile

I am trying to run an Electron app (that uses built-in webcam) in docker container but it gives me this error :

`[99:0420/110905.327515:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")`

Can anyone help me?

Here is my running command for docker:

`sudo docker run --privileged --net=host --env="DISPLAY" --volume="$HOME/.Xauthority:/root/.Xauthority:rw" -v /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket:/host/run/dbus/system_bus_socket -e DBUS_SYSTEM_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/host/run/dbus/system_bus_socket gui-app`

and if it helps, here is my Dockerfile

```
# use the version that corresponds to your electron version
FROM node:16

# install electron dependencies or more if your library has other dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install \
    git libx11-xcb1 libxcb-dri3-0 libxtst6 libnss3 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libxss1 libasound2 libdrm2 libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk3-module dbus libgbm1 \
    -yq --no-install-suggests --no-install-recommends \
    && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV GTK_MODULES=canberra-gtk-module

# copy the source into /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN chown -R node /app

# install node modules and perform an electron rebuild
USER node
RUN yarn
RUN npx electron-rebuild

# Electron needs root for sand boxing
# see https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/17972
USER root
RUN chown root /app/node_modules/electron/dist/chrome-sandbox
RUN chmod 4755 /app/node_modules/electron/dist/chrome-sandbox

RUN service dbus start

# Electron doesn't like to run as root
USER node
CMD ["yarn", "dev"]
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: If you're trying to run a desktop GUI application that needs access to hardware devices, both of these tasks require specific complex Docker-specific setup, and you will find it much easier to run this program outside a container.

Comment: @DavidMaze I am aware it is really challenging and there is lack of documentation about it but it’s what i need to accomplish right now. do you see specific problem on my script or on Dockerfile that causes this problem?

Comment: The one obvious thing I see is that you're not bind-mounting the X socket into the container, though that won't cause this DBus issue.  `RUN service ...` will do absolutely nothing (an image does not persist running processes) and you can delete that line.